# The named parameter 'color' isn't defined. for the 'ElevatedButton' flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, mobile-application

I am working on a mobile app project on Flutter. In the page I have created, I put a button with redirect functionality. But when I try to paint the button it raises an error : The named parameter 'color' isn't defined.

```
            Center( 
                child: ElevatedButton(
                   onPressed: () {
                    // add your redirect functionality here
                   },                
                   child: const Text(
                     'Button with redirect functionality',
                     style: TextStyle(
                       color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                              
                  ),
              ),
```

My source code for the mentioned buttoned is above. I would be appreciated and grateful If someone tell what is going wrong with that

Thank you so much for your interest

I have tried to do use the color parameter with different objects but got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the property "backgroundColor".
Like this:

```
Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // add your redirect functionality here
        },
        child: const Text(
          'Button with redirect functionality',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
           backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```